# Show whitespace characters in printout

Tags: printing, whitespace

I need to render an ASCII file for printing in a way that removes ambiguity if (very unlikely) one decides to type it in and validate the signatures.

I am giving the 8-bit symbol-set QR code as an alternative, but a manual validation would be a nice addition for archival purposes.

Essentially, I need a monospace typesetter that would typeset a 'blank space' symbol for space, a CR/LF symbol (and proceed to the next line for readability) whenever a CR/LF is encountered, etc., making it obvious if there are any trailing whitespaces before the CR/LF, if there is a character present, etc.

Is there a font that accomplishes that goal? *nix utility? TeX module/package/derived system? I've posted a similar question on TeX.SE, but it might be better suited here.

Answer (score 29):

As an extension to savanto's answer, I've created a `whitespace` bash alias to show whitespace in any output using appropriate Unicode characters. Just pipe to it and have fun!

```sh
# SP  ' '  0x20 = · U+00B7 Middle Dot
# TAB '\t' 0x09 = ￫ U+FFEB Halfwidth Rightwards Arrow
# CR  '\r' 0x0D = § U+00A7 Section Sign (⏎ U+23CE also works fine)
# LF  '\n' 0x0A = ¶ U+00B6 Pilcrow Sign (was "Paragraph Sign")
alias whitespace="sed 's/ /·/g;s/\t/￫/g;s/\r/§/g;s/$/¶/g'"
```

Have fun!

```
$ bash --help | whitespace
GNU·bash,·version·4.4.20(1)-release-(x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)¶
Usage:￫bash·[GNU·long·option]·[option]·...¶
￫bash·[GNU·long·option]·[option]·script-file·...¶
GNU·long·options:¶
￫--debug¶
￫--debugger¶
￫--dump-po-strings¶
￫--dump-strings¶
￫--help¶
￫--init-file¶
￫--login¶
￫--noediting¶
￫--noprofile¶
￫--norc¶
￫--posix¶
￫--rcfile¶
￫--restricted¶
￫--verbose¶
￫--version¶
Shell·options:¶
￫-ilrsD·or·-c·command·or·-O·shopt_option￫￫(invocation·only)¶
￫-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP·or·-o·option¶
Type·`bash·-c·"help·set"'·for·more·information·about·shell·options.¶
Type·`bash·-c·help'·for·more·information·about·shell·builtin·commands.¶
Use·the·`bashbug'·command·to·report·bugs.¶
¶
bash·home·page:·<http://www.gnu.org/software/bash>¶
General·help·using·GNU·software:·<http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>¶
```

Answer (score 10):

On a unix/linux system, you can pipe the file through `tr`, converting certain characters to others. For example:

```
cat file.txt | tr ' \n' '#$'
```

will translate all spaces to `#` and all newlines to `$`.

If you need to transform CR/LF together, you can use `tr ' ' '#'` to change spaces, and pipe output into another `tr -t '\r\n' '$'` to change the newlines. The `-t` tells `tr` to truncate the matched set to the length of the replacement set.

You could also use the utility `dos2unix` to first translate all the `\r\n` line endings to the more unix `\n`, then use the first option.

Example (with `\n` only):

```
$ echo "foo bar" | tr ' \n' '#$'
foo#bar$
```